# Looking for an "intuitive" regular expression for $\{ w \in \Sigma^{\ast} \mid 2|w|_1 + |w|_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let $L \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ with $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$ be the language such that two times the number of $1$'s in a word in $L$ plus the number of $0$'s is divisible by $3$, i.e. if we denote by $|w|_1$ the number the symbol $1$ occurs in $w$ and by $|w|_0$ the number the symbols $0$ occurs, then
$$
 L = \{ w \in \Sigma^{\ast} \mid 2|w|_1 + |w|_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \}.
$$
I know this language to be regular, as it is quite easy to give an automaton for it. I also got a (quite complicated) regular expression for it using an algorithm going from the automaton. But is there any regular expression that is easy in the sense that it gives some insight into why it is a regular expression for the language?

Not that for example for the language $\{ w \mid |w|_0 \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \}$ it is quite easy to give a regular expression, it would be $1^{\ast}(01^{\ast}01^{\ast}01^{\ast})^{\ast}$, or for $\{ w \mid |w| \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \}$ as it would be $(\Sigma\Sigma\Sigma)^{\ast}$. But the above language somehow combines these conditions.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was an intuitive regexp for this. The language is defined based on a global property of the string and regular expressions for that kind of property are usually unpleasant.

Comment: I mean a regexp representing that structure somehow, or which could be derived with some arguments about the structure of the language, it need not the be short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The automaton for that language is, as you say, extremely simple: it consists of a triangle, in which 0s move clockwise and 1s move counterclockwise:

[image: DFA for language]

A classic way to turn this into a regular expression is to eliminate states one at a time, converting transitions through each state into regular expressions. Eliminating state 2 is easy since there are no epsilon transitions or self-loops, so we end up with:

$$\begin{align}s0 \to s0&: 10 \\
s0 \to s1&: 0 + 11 \\
s1 \to s0&: 1 + 00 \\
s1 \to s1&: 01 \\
\end{align}$$

When we then eliminate state 1, we produce a relatively simple regular expression:

$$(10 + (0+11)(01)^*(1+00))^*$$

Is that regex intuitive? I guess that depends on your intuitions. $10$ and $01$ both have no effect on $2|w|_1 + |w|_0 \pmod{3}$; $0+11$ adds 1, and $1+00$ subtracts 1. So the regex definitely shows the path around the three possible values of $2|w|_1 + |w|_0 \pmod{3}$

Comment: so what about 111100   or 110000 ...

Comment: @phillip: $2*4+2$ is 1 mod 3, and $2*2+4$ is 2. So neither are in $L$. Or am I missimg something?

Comment: oops. oops.. oops.  I took as number of bits .. my mistake  Alright...   these would be  00001 1100  111  111000  11110

Comment: @PhillipWilliams: Grep says those all match. For example, `1100` takes the second alternative, starting with `11` then no repetitions of `01`, then `00`. Ball's in your court.

Comment: Alright, where is 0011 ?     (10+(0+11)(01)∗(1+00))∗  does not seem to allow to start with 0

Comment: @PhillipWilliams: (It's important to note that I'm using `+` as the alternation operator, as is common in academic contexts. It's usual to write the non-empty repetition operator as $r^+$, not $r+$.) From the second alternative ($(0+11)(01)^*(1+00)$): `0` `01` `1`. My conclusion is that the regular expression (although it is correct) is evidently not intuitive :-)

Comment: to me, + is one or more * is 0 or more,  and | is OR  .. what does your GREP command look like ?  as with any communication, common reference is a must

Comment: @PhillipWilliams: To make it work with grep, I changed the `+`'s to `|`, since that is how alternation is spelled by grep. If this were a programming site, I probably would have written the regular expression that way, too.

Comment: it was still interesting to look at .   Have not been in Academic in about 35 years

Comment: @PhillipWilliams: Anyway, I apologise for not having realised there was a simple misunderstanding earlier. For what it's worth, the tag info for [regular-expressions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/regular-expressions/info) does show both operators. ("often $+$ is used")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60456/discussion-between-phillip-williams-and-rici).

Answer (score 1):

To complement rici's answer, I just add a run of [Kleene's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_algorithm), giving another regular expression (starting from his automaton):

\begin{align*}
 R^{-1}_{00} & = \varepsilon \\ 
 R^{-1}_{01} & = 0 \\
 R^{-1}_{02} & = 1 \\
 R^{-1}_{11} & = \varepsilon \\ 
 R^{-1}_{10} & = 1 \\ 
 R^{-1}_{12} & = 0 \\
 R^{-1}_{22} & = \varepsilon \\ 
 R^{-1}_{21} & = 1 \\ 
 R^{-1}_{20} & = 0 
\end{align*}
and further:
\begin{align*}
 R^2_{00} & = R_{02}^1 (R_{22}^1)^{\ast} R^1_{20} | R_{00}^1 \\
 R^1_{00} & = R_{00}^0 (R_{11}^0)^{\ast} R^0_{10} | R_{00}^0 
            = \varepsilon (10|\varepsilon)^{\ast} 1 | \varepsilon
            = (10)^{\ast} 1 | \varepsilon \\
 R^0_{00} & = R_{00}^{-1} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{00}^{-1} | R_{00}^{-1}
            = \varepsilon (\varepsilon)^{\ast}\varepsilon | \varepsilon
            = \varepsilon \\
 R^0_{11} & = R_{10}^{-1} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{01}^{-1} | R_{11}^{-1} 
            = 1 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} 0 | \varepsilon 
            = 10 | \varepsilon \\
 R^0_{10} & = R_{10}^{-1} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{00}^{-1} | R_{10}^{-1} 
            = 1 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} \varepsilon | 1 
            = 1 \\
 R^1_{02} & = R^0_{10} (R_{11}^0)^{\ast} R_{12}^0 | R_{02}^0 
            = 1 ( 10|\varepsilon )^{\ast} (11 | 0) | 1 
            = ( 1 (10)^{\ast}(11 | 0)) | 1\\ 
 R^0_{12} & = R^{-1}_{10} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{02}^{-1} | R_{12}^{-1} 
            = 1 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} 1 | 0 
            = 11 | 0 \\
 R^0_{02} & = R^{-1}_{00} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{02}^{-1} | R_{02}^{-1} 
            = \varepsilon (\varepsilon)^{\ast} 1 | 1 
            = 1 \\
 R^1_{22} & = R^0_{21} (R_{11}^0)^{\ast} R_{12}^0 | R_{22}^0  
            = (00 | 1)(10|\varepsilon)^{\ast} (11|0) | (01|\varepsilon)
            = (00 | 1)(10)^{\ast} (11|0) | (01|\varepsilon) \\ 
 R^0_{22} & = R_{20}^{-1} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{02}^{-1} | R_{22}^{-1}
            = 0 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} 1 | \varepsilon 
            = 01 | \varepsilon \\
 R^0_{21} & = R^{-1}_{20} (R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{01}^{-1} | R_{21}^{-1} 
            = 0 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} 0 | 1 
            = 00 | 1 \\
 R^1_{20} & = R^0_{21} (R_{11}^0)^{\ast} R_{10}^0 | R_{20}^0 
            = (00|1)(10|\varepsilon)^{\ast} 1 | 0 
            = (00|1)(10)^{\ast}1 | 0 \\
 R^0_{20} & = R^{-1}_{20}(R_{00}^{-1})^{\ast} R_{00}^{-1} | R_{20}^{-1} 
            = 0 (\varepsilon)^{\ast} \varepsilon | 0 
            = 0 
\end{align*}
so we have all subterms to give the final answer
$$
 R_{00}^2 = ( ( 1 (10)^{\ast}(11 | 0)) | 1 )
            ( (00 | 1)(10)^{\ast} (11|0) | (01|\varepsilon) )^{\ast} 
            ( (00|1)(10)^{\ast}1 | 0 ) | 
            ( (10)^{\ast} 1 | \varepsilon )           
$$
which is unfortunately much more complicated.