# Does there exist a finite automaton for the given language?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

The question is simple and given as, alphabet $A$ is $\{a, b\}$, and language $L$ over $A$:

$L = \{w: w \in \{a, b\}^*, n(a) - n(b) = 1 \mod 3\}$. Here $n(a)$ = number of $a$ and $n(b)$ is number of $b$.

My answer is that it's not a regular language because the modular expression can be simplified as. $n(a) =n(b) +3k+1$ and hence there is a comparison in between the two alphabets. Further comparison are infinite but a finite automaton has only finite memory which are associated with states.

So we can say the above language is not regular hence no finite automaton for it. But there is a problem, I have read a book by Linz in which the above question was given stating that find the regular expression for it. I am a bit confused so any help will be appreciated. I would also be interested in a general approach to answer this type of question.

Comment: "because the modular expression can be simplified as [something] and hence there is a comparison in between the two alphabets" -- that sentence doesn't make _any_ sense to me. Which to alphabets? What kind of "comparison"?

Comment: @Raphael "alphabet" should be "symbol" and I think it's trying to convey the intuition that the language can't be regular for basically the same reason that $\{a^nb^n\mid n\geq 0\}$ isn't: you have to remember how many $a$s and $b$s you've seen and you'd need infinitely many different states to cover the infinite number of possibilities. (In this case, the intuition is incorrect, but I that's what it's getting at.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Ah, gotcha. The "because" threw me since there is no kind of reasonable reasoning (be-dum-dum-tss) here.

Comment: Very similar: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74741/looking-for-an-intuitive-regular-expression-for-w-in-sigma-ast-mid-2/74748 (since $a+2b$ and $a-b$ are identical mod 3)

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning about comparisons would be correct, if there were infinitely many numbers. But there's only three of them modulo $3$.

The automaton can be constructed directly. You need three states, one for each of the residues: $0$, $1$ and $2$. Then every $a$-transition should correspond to an increment and $b$-transition to a decrement.

Comment: i have tried that way but i was unable to form  dfa since in last state(remainder =2 ) where addition of a leads to first state of remainder 0 and b leads to one decreament. but what about addition of b at state having remainder 0 and if we do so then the equation is unstatisfied

Comment: @low_burning $2$ and $-1$ are the same modulo $3$.

Comment: thanks and i really appreciate its been a while since i get rid of this stuff , thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Dimitri has already said, the number of comparisons will only be 3.
Consider the three states:
q0 - where the n(a) - n(b) mod 3  = 0

q1 - where n(a) - n(b) mod 3 = 1

q2 - where n(a) -n(b) mode 3 = 2

Out of these q1 will be final state.

The DFA will be:
[image: DFA]

Note:
If we get n(b) more than n(a). say n(a) is 0  and n(b) is 2, the automaton still works as -2 mod 3 is 1.